# Output Caching with Specific Interval Time to refresh contents

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I am developing a feature on Dot Net MVC to display top bar similar to HelloBar.

This has different texts with start and end date /time. Depending on current date/time, it should display.

I am implementing Output Cache and configured it for 10 minutes. Now, depending on date time, I am not able to display it correctly when using Caching.

For example, Hellobar text is configured to display between 12 pm to 12:20 pm. But suppose the new request comes at 12:15 pm, then it caches for time up to 12:25 pm. But I have another Hellobar text to display at that time, which is not displayed.

What is the best way to implement caching in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly remove any page from the output cache by calling the HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem method. You can do this from the global.asax file, a custom ASP.NET server control you have created, or from a page, depending upon the needs of your application.